# What does "extend your house" mean? Is it correct to say "expand your house"?

Tags: meaning

"You can add value to your house by extending or renovating it."
I came across this phrase in Oxford dictionary. But I cannot really understand why the word "extend" is used here. Could you please explain what it means. Can we use the word expand here? Will there be any difference in meaning?

And another question:
The company plans to extend its operations into Europe. 
The company plans to expand its market presence in Europe.
What's the difference between these two phrases? Can we interchange the verbs extend and expand in these phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **extending**, they mean *creating an addition or, simply, adding on* to a house by configuring new space. So it's the act of making improvements to a home by building on a new room, a back patio, a loft, or something similar. In other words, it's an action that enlarges the home physically.

---

The difference between (a) **extend its operations** and (b) **expand its market presence** is as follows:

(a) **Extending operations** is the actual physical act of increasing the scope of company operations within a certain geographic area. It involves movement, activity and a direct involvement on the part of the company to realize this goal.

(b) **Expanding market presence** is a more ephemeral goal; expanding market presence could mean increasing awareness through advertising, public relations, charitable contributions, etc.; announcing future intention to do business in a new region; and/or increasing already existing levels of development and production to newsworthy new levels.